# How to stop Flutter updating/updating dart on Windows

Tags: flutter, dart

I had installed VS Code/Flutter/Dart and it was working fine, but after downloading and opening a sample flutter project my Flutter/Dart setup has gone into an infinite loop of trying to update Dart. It is being blocked by my work proxy or something.

I fixed the flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk folder to the latest (2.18.4) and updated the pubspec.yaml in the project to use only that version, yet flutter is still stuck trying to update.

How can I stop it? I don't think my work will allow flutter through the proxy.

And why is it even running, I have the latest and I'm telling my project to use the latest.

Comment: You could use flutter version manager (fvm) to manage multiple versions at the same time

Comment: Proxy also blocks the install of fvm...

Comment: I ended up downloading Flutter from scratch and has stopped trying to update the dart sdk. At least for now.